# Мне необходимо вывести данные на веб-сайт, но часть функций не работают

Tags: python, django, функции

Я пишу калькулятор по сопромату на Django, но возникла проблема - почему-то функция F не срабатывает. Вот мой код:

````
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponseNotFound
from .forms import InputForm
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds

def index(request):
    form = InputForm()
    return render(request, 'work/numbers.html', {'form': form})

def create(request):
    form = InputForm(request.POST)
    #rez1 = None  
    #rez2 = None  
    if form.is_valid():
        var1 = form.cleaned_data['var1']
        var2 = form.cleaned_data['var2']
        var3 = form.cleaned_data['var3']
        var4 = form.cleaned_data['var4']
        var5 = form.cleaned_data['var5']
        var6 = form.cleaned_data['var6']
        var7 = form.cleaned_data['var7']
        var8 = form.cleaned_data['var8']
        var9 = form.cleaned_data['var9']
        var10 = form.cleaned_data['var10']
        var11 = form.cleaned_data['var11']
        var12 = form.cleaned_data['var12']
        var = form.cleaned_data['var']
        
        rez1, rez2 = opt(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12, var)
        
        return render(request, 'work/numbers.html', {'form': form, 'rez1': rez1, 'rez2': rez2})
    else:
        form = InputForm() 
        return render(request, 'work/numbers.html', {'form': form})

def gaussElimin(a, b):
    # Implementation of gaussElimin function
    n = len(b)
    for k in range(0, n-1):
        for i in range(k+1, n):
            if a[k, k] != 0.0:
                lam = a[i, k] / a[k, k]
                a[i, k+1:n] = a[i, k+1:n] - lam * a[k, k+1:n]
                b[i] = b[i] - lam * b[k]
    for k in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        b[k] = (b[k] - np.dot(a[k, k+1:n], b[k+1:n])) / a[k, k]
    return b

def downhill(F, xStart, side=1, tol=0.1):
    # xStart - начальный вектор данных
    # side - длина стороны симплекса (по умолчанию 0.1)
    n = len(xStart)  # Число варьируемых параметров
    x = np.zeros((n+1, n))
    f = np.zeros(n+1)

    # создаем начальный симплекс:
    x[0] = xStart
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        x[i] = xStart
        x[i, i-1] = xStart[i-1] + side

    # определение значений функции F в вершинах симплекса:
    for i in range(n+1):
        f[i] = F(x[i])

    # Главный цикл
    for k in range(4000):
        # Находим вершины с наибольшим и наименьшим значениями:
        iLo = np.argmin(f)
        iHi = np.argmax(f)
        # Вычисляем вектор смещения:
        d = (-(n+1) * x[iHi] + np.sum(x, axis=0)) / n
        # Проверка условия достижения минимума:
        if math.sqrt(np.dot(d, d) / n) < tol:
            return x[iLo]

        # Попытка отражения 
        xNew = x[iHi] + 2.0 * d
        fNew = F(xNew)
        if fNew <= f[iLo]:  # то принимаем отражение
            x[iHi] = xNew
            f[iHi] = fNew

            # Пытаемся еще продлить отражение
            xNew = x[iHi] + d
            fNew = F(xNew)
            if fNew <= f[iLo]:  # то принмиаем продление
                x[iHi] = xNew
                f[iHi] = fNew
        else:
            # Снова пробуем продление:
            if fNew <= f[iHi]:  # то принмиаем продление
                x[iHi] = xNew
                f[iHi] = fNew
            else:
                # Применяем сжатие
                xNew = x[iHi] + 0.5 * d
                fNew = F(xNew)
                if fNew <= f[iHi]:  # то принмиаем продление
                    x[iHi] = xNew
                    f[iHi] = fNew
                else:
                    # Используем уменьшение площади
                    for i in range(len(x)):
                        if i != iLo:
                            x[i] = (x[i] - x[iLo]) * 0.5
                            f[i] = F(x[i])
    print("Too many iterations in downhill")
    return x[iLo]

def F(x, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12):
   
    A1_var = float(var1)
    A3_var = float(var2)
    A4_var = float(var3)
    E1_var = float(var4)
    E2_var = float(var5)
    E3_var = float(var6)
    E4_var = float(var7)
    L1_var = float(var8)
    L3_var = float(var9)
    L4_var = float(var10)
    F1_var = float(var11)
    F2_var = float(var12)  

    elementNodes = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]])
    numberNodes = elementNodes.max()
    numberElements = elementNodes.shape[0]
    prescribedDof = np.array([1, 4])
    A = np.array([A1_var, A1_var, A3_var, A4_var])
    E = np.array([E1_var, E2_var, E3_var, E4_var])
    L = np.array([L1_var, x[0], L3_var, L4_var])
    L_obr = 1 / L
    k_st = E * A / L
    V = A[0] * L[0] + A[1] * L[1] + A[2] * L[2] + A[3] * L[3]
    displacements = np.zeros((numberNodes, 1))
    force = np.zeros((numberNodes, 1))
    stiffness = np.zeros((numberNodes, numberNodes))
    Sigma = np.zeros((numberElements, 1))

    force[1] = F1_var
    force[2] = F2_var

    for e in range(0, numberElements):
        elementDof = elementNodes[e]
        stiffness[elementDof[0] - 1, elementDof[0] - 1] = stiffness[elementDof[0] - 1, elementDof[0] - 1] + k_st[e]
        stiffness[elementDof[0] - 1, elementDof[1] - 1] = stiffness[elementDof[0] - 1, elementDof[1] - 1] - k_st[e]
        stiffness[elementDof[1] - 1, elementDof[0] - 1] = stiffness[elementDof[1] - 1, elementDof[0] - 1] - k_st[e]
        stiffness[elementDof[1] - 1, elementDof[1] - 1] = stiffness[elementDof[1] - 1, elementDof[1] - 1] + k_st[e]

    stiffness2 = stiffness
    Nodes_num = list(range(1, numberNodes + 1))
    activeDof = []
    for i in Nodes_num:
        if i not in prescribedDof:
            activeDof.append(i)

    stiffness2 = np.delete(stiffness2, (prescribedDof - 1), axis=1)
    stiffness2 = np.delete(stiffness2, (prescribedDof - 1), axis=0)
    force2 = force
    force2 = np.delete(force2, (prescribedDof - 1), axis=0)

    displacements2 = gaussElimin(stiffness2, force2)
    for i in range(0, len(activeDof)):
        displacements[activeDof[i] - 1] = displacements2[i]
    Reactions = np.dot(stiffness, displacements)

    for i in range(0, numberElements):
        Sigma[i] = E[i] / L[i] * (displacements[i+1] - displacements[i])
    dd = (displacements[2]).tolist()
    dd1 = dd[0]

    return V + (displacements[3] * 10000) + (x[0] - 50)**4 + (x[1] - 150)**2 + (Sigma[1] - 500) * 2

def opt(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12, var):
    

    rez1 = 'error'
    rez2 = 'error'
    try:
        if var == 0:
            xStart = np.array([50, 100])
            x = downhill(lambda x: F(x, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12), xStart)
            rezult1 = int(x[0])
            rezult2 = int(x[1])
            rez1 = str(rezult1)
            rez2 = str(rezult2)
        elif var == 1:
            bounds = Bounds([10, 10], [200, 200])
            xStart = np.array([50, 100]) 
            x = minimize(lambda x: F(x, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12), xStart, method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bounds, options={'disp': True})
            rez1 = str(int(x.x[0]))
            rez2 = str(int(x.x[1]))
    except:
        rez1 = 'error'
        rez2 = 'error'
    
    return rez1, rez2
#print(F.A1_var)```
````

Comment: Насколько я вижу, ты передаешь не функцию, а её результат. Замени примерно на downhill(F). Естественно аргументы передавай по другому

Comment: было бы неплохо увидеть [mcve]

Comment: @Pet Linux, код выводит значения 'error', которые присваиваются в функции opt

Comment: @IgirehI, прочитайте по ссылке выше.